# Let $f$ be an entire function s.t. $F(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(z)$ exists for all $z$ with local uniform convergence. What can we say about $F$?

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have stumbled into this problem, without a given answer.

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $F(z) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(z)$ exists $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ with local uniform convergence.

> 1. What can you say about the function $F$?
> 2. What can you say about the function $f$?

I have sort of convinced myself that $F(z) =Ce^z$ and thus $f(z)=F(z)$ but i am very doubtful about this and even if it is correct I have no idea how to prove it, and there is probably more information you have to provide about the given functions. Such that $F$ is analytic implies that $f$ is analytic.

Comment: Any polynomial also satisfies your premise. Also, $\sin(\lambda z),\cos(\lambda z),\sinh(\lambda z),\cosh(\lambda z)$ where $|\lambda|<1$. And by whole, do you mean entire?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a nice question. First note that if $f$ is entire then so are all its derivatives and therefore $F$  is also entire. Then consider the sequence $f^{(n+1)}$ which converges to $F'$. What does that imply? Finally, to characterize $f$, consider $g = f - F$. What can you say about the sequence $g^{(n)}$? What does that imply?

Comment: Ok. So $f^{n+1} $converges to$ F' $so$ f^{n}$ also converges to $F' so f(x) = F(x)$? I do not quite understand what you mean characterize $f$. I'd say that $g$ uniformely converges to $0$. But if this is the case doesnt it disprove Vercassivelaunos comment about any given polynomial also satisfies the premise?

Comment: $F'=F$ so $F'(z)=0$ or $F'(z)=Ce^z, C \ne 0$; assuming the latter case, then $g=f-Ce^z$ satisfisies the same property as $f$ but with $F_g=0$ so the general form of the solution is $f(z)=Ce^z+f_0, C \ne 0$ for which $f_0$ satisfies the property with limit zero; note that polynomials and entire functions of the type $h(z)=g(\lambda z), 0<|\lambda|<1$ where $|g^{(n)}(z)| \le C_R, |z| \le R$ uniformly in $n$ work (any convex combinations of $e^{\alpha_k z}, |\alpha_k| \le 1$ are examples of the latter))

Comment: I do not quite follow. If $f(z)=Ce^z + f_{0}$ then $F(z)=Ce^z +f_{0}z + c \neq f(z)$? And have no clue what you mean by the last part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already worked out in the comments, $F(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(z)$ (locally uniformly) implies that
$$
F'(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f^{(n+1)}(z) = F(z)
$$
so that $F(z) = Ce^z$ for some constant $C \in \Bbb C$.

Then $g(z) = f(z) - Ce^z$ satisfies
$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty} g^{(n)}(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty}  f^{(n)}(z) - Ce^z = F(z) - Ce^z = 0
$$
so that it remains to characterize all entire functions $g$ with the property that
$$ 
\lim_{n\to\infty} g^{(n)}(z)  = 0
$$
locally uniformly in $\Bbb C$. Writing $g$ as a power series $g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b_k}{k!} z^k$ we have the necessary condition
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} b_k = \lim_{k\to\infty} g^{(k)}(0) = 0 \,.
$$
That condition is also sufficient: If $b_k \to 0$ then for $|z| \le R$
$$
 \left|  g^{(n)}(z) \right| =  \left|  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b_{k+n}
}{k!} z^k\right|
\le   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{|b_{k+n}|
}{k!} R^k \, .
$$
Given $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose $N$ such that $|b_n| < \epsilon e^{-R}$ for $n > N$, which implies that
$$
\left|  g^{(n)}(z) \right| \le  \epsilon e^{-R} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} R^k = \epsilon
$$
for $n > N$ and $|z| \le R$.

*Summarizing the results:* If $f$ is a an entire function then $(f^{(n)})$ converges locally uniformly in $\Bbb C$  if and only if
$$
 f(z) = Ce^z + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b_k}{k!} z^k
$$
for some $C \in \Bbb C$ and some sequence $(b_k)$ of complex numbers converging to zero. In that case the limit function is $F(z) = Ce^z $.

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around this. I can only see two options, Either the series converges to $0$ and there is no point in expressing it or it converges to some other complex number. But then then function F cannot be it's own derivative.

Comment: @Firefox: Sorry, I don't get what you are saying. If $f(z) = Ce^z + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b_k}{k!} z^k$ and $b_k \to 0$ then $ f^{(n)}(z) = Ce^z + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b_{k+n}
}{k!} z^k \to  Ce^z$ for $n \to \infty$, so that $F(z) = Ce^z$ is the limit function.

Comment: I understand that $f^{(n)}$ converges to $F$ but shouldnt $F'(z)=F(z)$?

Comment: @Firefox: If $F(z) = Ce^z$ then $F'(z) = Ce^z = F(z)$.

Comment: I think that I am asking the wrong questions. Also I have probably confused $f$ with $F'$

Comment: @Firefox: Just let me know which part in my answer is unclear.