# Does there exist $f(x): \mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^+}$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f^{(n)}(x) = g(x) \not\equiv 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, soft-question

I am searching for the existence of a real value function defined on the positive quadrant such that as you take more derivative, it converges. What I mean is does there exist a class of function $f(x): \mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f^{(n)}(x) = g(x) \not\equiv 0$, where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the n-th derivative of $f$.

For example, let's $f(x) = 2x$, then for $n>2$, $f^{(n)} = 0$, so the "derivative converges". From this example, any polynomial function also has this property. However, if I exclude trivial convergence ($\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f^{(n)}(x) = 0$), are there still some classes of functions that satisfy this condition?

Comment: $f(x) = e^x$?...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, the exponential function is one that came to mind. I wonder if there is a general class for something like this. Possibly $e^{f(x)}$ with some special condition on $f(x)$.

Comment: These are functions that are eigenvectors of differentiation operators (the limit only converging to a "fixed point" in the sense of operator iteration)

Comment: @NinadMunshi Could you please elaborate?

Comment: For analytic functions in the complex plane see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3760485/let-f-be-an-entire-function-s-t-fz-lim-n-to-infty-fnz-exists

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much! I think I can work out something similar for real functions.